# Question about movies to watch

Tags: discussion, status-declined

Can we ask on this forum about recommendations of movies we could watch? Questions like: "What new do you think is worth from ?", "What do you think about , is it worth to watch? "

Comment: As a thing to point out, this is not a forum, but a Q&A site about movies, therefore opinions are generally not allowed as they are just that, opinions.  The success of this site depends on how much factual information we can produce based on the questions that we receive.

Answer (score 8):

Recommendation questions were discussed early in the beta, in [this question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/dealing-with-recommendation-questions)

Given the question seems to fairly strongly recommend not allowing recommendations and gets 9 votes against an answer highlighting some sites have 'temporary' policies allowing them which gets 4 votes - the balance seems to weigh against recommendations.

This community has a fairly strong feeling about '[list questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/list-of-movies-question-can-we-allow-it)' too - of which recommendation questions would probably fall under.

The main arguments seem to be that recommendations are more about subjective opinion than most questions, and that they would tend to solicit lists which does not fit a question and answer site.

We do have a chat room for which recommendation discussions would be fine.

Comment: +1 for wording it well

Comment: yeah, recommendations would kill this site.