# can we ask for suggestion on which TV series/movie to watch by providing genre and reference movie?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, tv

Can we ask for suggestions on which TV series/movie to watch of a particular genre?

Let's say I want to know all the TV series that are similar to `Big Bang Theory` and would want to know which one of them is a better option and why.

Comment: [No](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/232/114/e39.png)

Comment: lmao @tylershads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recommendation questions have been decided on as off-topic previously by the community.  [Question about movies to watch](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/question-about-movies-to-watch)

Coming from a failed beta site that allowed recommendations, I can't say they add any real value to a site.  IMHO they're less useful than identification questions, and those are argued over all of the time.

Comment: ok, fair enough