# Proposal for a new type of question: Movie Recommendation

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I believe that we should create a new tag/question kind about movie recommendations. This is just an idea, don't hate me for it.

I believe that, when asked well, a movie recommendation question can contribute to the overall knowledge of the site as users could look for movies that they might want to watch.

## Example question:

---

## Movies about dolls coming to life

I like to watch movies about dolls coming to life and have seen a lot/some/a few movies about them. I have already seen:

- movie 1
- movie 2
- movie 3

and can't find any other good films. Could anyone recommend any good movies like this?

### OR

## Movies starting Shia LaBeouf

Does anyone know any good movies that star Shia LaBeouf? I really enjoyed him in Transformers and Indiana Jones and was wondering if anyone could tell me some good movies with him in?

I have already seen

- movie 1
- movie 2
- series of movies

---

## Example answer:

---

## *Movie*

I particularly liked this movie when I watched it. It was very suspenseful and kept me hooked the whole time. I have recommended it to my friends and they all liked it.

It was released in *year* in *language* and was well received on the big screen. It also had *x* sequels made and they were all good movies.

If *language* isn't your native language, it has been dubbed into

- English
- Spanish
- French

Here is a short summary from Wikipedia/my experience/friend's experience:

*summary*

---

The user will accept the answer that they think is the best answer or, if they believe there is more than one winner, they can upvote them.

This would also apply to tv shows where the questioner can post series they have already watched.

---

I think I have everything but if you still have any questions, please ask in the comments.

Comment: ...... No ......

Comment: @NapoleonWilson why not?

Comment: Because of everything SE stands for and because those things go terribly wrong and did so already on a multitude of sites. I'm sure someone will soon put that into a proper answer, or I will. (I'm also pretty sure this was discussed, and dismissed, very early in the site's lifetime already anyway.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson please do. I'm interested to see why you think this is a bad idea, explained fully.

Comment: Short answer: if ID hasn't killed us yet, this will. ;-)

Comment: A generic "ID this thing site" has been recommended on A51 repeatedly and gets deleted repeatedly. Same thing with _____ recommendation. I think the only recommendation sites that have been allowed are hardware and software recs. They even closed down the original Literature proposal due to low-quality questions, mostly lit recommendation... we really don't want to go down that path.

Comment: For some history, see this post on A51: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25600/131135

Comment: While there are [Soft](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)/[Hardware](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Recommendation sites which appear to fit and work well with the SE Model it should be noted that they have strict guidelines on how you request/recommend and ultimately one answer solves the Asker's problem and is "more correct" than the rest (ie. first more to what is asked)

Comment: @RobertCartaino Awww, and I so wished to slap a `status-declined` onto it. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

This has been **specifically** off topic [since the creation of this site](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/dealing-with-recommendation-questions). It falls under the "primarily opinion based" close reason.

From Grace Note's question linked above:

> Recommendations were in fact noted as off-topic during the definition phase, and there's no trace of them in the top voted on-topic questions.

Everyone has their own favorite ______ movie. There's no one "correct" answer. What makes my recommendation of one film better or worse than yours? Nothing. Inevitably, these questions turn into a movie popularity contest with well-known films "winning" over lesser-known ones. These questions would be handing out reputation to users for doing nothing other than voicing their opinion, which is completely counter to the Stack Exchange format, which is designed to recognize subject expertise.

The *only* place I've seen on SE that these work is on the existing sites for [Hardware](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Recommendations and I think these work **because** they require extremely specific questions and require that answers be supported with explanations for why a product solves the user's problem.

All this said, you're more than welcome to come chat with us in [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) to get recommendations!

Comment: @user00001 why not? If you have any complain towards the chatroom feel free to express.